# Finding Eigenvalues for $y''+\lambda y=0$ with boundary conditions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the equation $y''+\lambda y=0$ and boundary conditions $y(1)=0$ and $y(0)+y'(0)=0$.

Let $r=\pm\sqrt{-\lambda}.$

If $\lambda >0$ we have $y=C_1\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+C_2\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x).$  Applying our boundary conditions I get to this point: $-\sqrt{\lambda}=\tan(\sqrt{\lambda}).$  At this point I'm not sure what to do .

Similarly for the case of $\lambda <0$.  This means that $r=\pm\sqrt{\lambda}$.  I believe this means I have to apply the conditions to $y=C_1e^{\sqrt{\lambda}x}+C_2e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}x}$.

I want to make sure my approach for the second case is correct and I'm not sure how to finish up the first case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application of your boundary condition should give you
\begin{equation}
0 = C_{1} \cos(\sqrt{\lambda})+C_{2}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}) \qquad (y(1)=0)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
0 = C_{1} + C_{2}\sqrt{\lambda}  \qquad (y(0) + y'(0)=0)
\end{equation}
Take it from here.

EDIT: Can't add comment so I'll re-edit me partial solution.

Your roots are of the form
\begin{equation}
\pm i \sqrt{\lambda}
\end{equation}
Remembering that 
\begin{eqnarray}
e^{z} &=& e^{a+ib} \\
      &=& e^{a}(\cos(b)+i\sin(b)) 
\end{eqnarray}
You can then look at substituing in these forms and plug in your boundary conditions.

Comment: I think the derivative was messed up.  $y'(0)=C_1+C_2\sqrt{\lambda}$.  Also, $y(1)=0$.

Comment: I have those equations.  I'm not sure how to handle the cases that arise from $\lambda$ being positive and negative.

Comment: I see that I made a sign error with.  I'm still yielding $\sqrt{\lambda}=tan(\sqrt{\lambda})$.